# AdMob code not shows adbanner in screen

Tags: iphone, admob

i try to run the downloaded code from admob, but that not shows adbanner  in screen, even i uses publisher id in pice of code.
bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
Please answer.

Answer (score 0):

Enable test ads to check whether the problem is with your code or with AdMob:

```
GADRequest.isTesting = YES;
```

Comment: i try to run that code http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/ios/fundamentals.html but adBabber is not comes

Answer (score 0):

Do what jnic suggests. Also, check if there is a message from AdMob in the console. There might be a message that says not showing ads is normal.